# The right punctuation in the title

Tags: punctuation

What punctuation mark would be right in this article title? I incline to the colon, but I'm not sure.

> The Idеal Durаtion of a Kiss (?) Wоmen’s Opiniоn

Answer (score 1):

The correct punctuation mark would be the colon.

> The Idеal Durаtion of a Kiss: Wоmen’s Opiniоn

[This article](http://www.sussex.ac.uk/informatics/punctuation/essaysandletters/titlesandheadings) may help to format titles and headings in the correct way.  If you look at the list on the left, it will point to other sections of the full article on punctuation and it's uses.

Comment: I would also add *"A"* before *"women's"*.. **The Idеal Durаtion of a Kiss: A Wоmen’s Opiniоn**

Comment: @SovereignSun I would do that to if the plural was not being used.  As it is women (more that one woman's opinion) you cannot use "A" before it and having the title as originally planned is fine.